# Why is lush used as a synonym for alcoholic?

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin

Do you know any other synonyms for an alcoholic person different from alky/alkie or dipsomaniac which would be the scientific or specialized term?

Comment: The full OED says "lush" was a (slang) noun meaning "Liquor, drink" back in 1790, a century before it was first extended to mean a drunkard. Other than that, this is an Off Topic "list" question.

Comment: Have you checked any references, such as the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lush)?

Comment: The medical term is alcoholic.

Answer (score 1):

Etymology Online says the origin is "obscure" (uncertain, rather than unknown) except that the word has been used as both an adjective and a verb in connection with alcoholic drinks, so it isn't surprising it came to be used as a noun for an alcoholic.

Terms such as *drunk, drunkard, wino,* or *boozer* certainly aren't medical terms but are widely used.

More informal, slang terms will differ between English dialects, but British English slang terms include *alky* (spelling varies), and *pisshead*.

Comment: Another archaic possibility is topper, first known use 1661.